# How can I get p value

Tags: php, woocommerce, get

i am a beginner with php, i have one question, i have set up output from product with text input on page, how can i only get p as value? thank you all for help

with this code I get this product

```
echo $order->email_order_items_table();
```

and this is the output (from the image) that I get on the page, and I only need the value that I have marked

the result on the page with marked p values

[image]

Comment: You could load the DOM (HTML code) (http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) into a php variable/array and manipulate the data from there to output the contents of the `<p>` tag. I've used http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm simplehtmldom a few times before which is easier to use than the native PHP functions

Comment: I did not get an answer that could help me.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

First off, this has less to do with get and woocommerce than `php`/`js` themselves. If you define an id for the paragraph, you can straight forwardly retrieve this element's content or attributes by `javascript`(`getElementById()`). Alternatively, take a look at parsing HTML with javascript and select the, perhaps, first occurence of `<p>`.

Comment: You can call JS from PHP.

Comment: You can call python from PHP why not give him some python code too?

Comment: There are ways of handling Inline-Assembler in PHP, why not use this? What a rubbish comparison! JS in PHP is something different from Pyth in PHP.